# Black screen areas with gnome classic

Tags: gnome

I've (re)installed ubuntu 12.04 on my eeepc-1000h. I've installed gnome classic.
Everything was going vell, but now, with screen resolution 1024x600, i've got in each side of the desktop, a black area (+-20px width): the mouse pointer goes there, but mouse clicks don't work; windows maximized don't use those areas. The panels seem not affected by this: they fit along all the screen.
How can I remove those black areas?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with the overlay-scrollbar in gnome, try to remove it with:

`sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar`

Comment: Removing is not necesarry. You can try to disable it first with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false`.